# Tooltip is not showing full text on mouse hover

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, tooltip

I have a grid view in a vb.net web application. In grid view i have added a RowDataBound event for the tooltip on gridview column on mouse hover. But tooltip is not showing all the text of column of grid view in IE and chrome and in Mozilla it is showing full text without any scroll bar. Is it possible to have a scroll bar in tool tip.The code is given below...

```
 Protected Sub ManageMessageGridView_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
        If e.Row.RowType.Equals(DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then
            Dim lblMsglWithToolTip As Label = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblMessage"), Label)
            Dim lblMsgTitleWithToolTip As Label = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblMessageTitle"), Label)
            Dim strMsgFullText As String = lblMsglWithToolTip.Text
            Dim strMsgTitleFullText As String = lblMsgTitleWithToolTip.Text

            If lblMsglWithToolTip.Text.Length > 100 Then
                lblMsglWithToolTip.Text = lblMsglWithToolTip.Text.Substring(0, 100) + "..."
            End If
            If lblMsgTitleWithToolTip.Text.Length > 20 Then
                lblMsgTitleWithToolTip.Text = lblMsgTitleWithToolTip.Text.Substring(0, 20) + "..."
            End If
            lblMsglWithToolTip.ToolTip = strMsgFullText
            lblMsgTitleWithToolTip.ToolTip = strMsgTitleFullText
        End If
    End Sub
```

Any help will be appreciated..Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Is it possible to have a scroll bar in tool tip*. Nop